# CIE-L*u*v* color interpolation

Tags: graphics, colors, physics, interpolation

I'm writing a vertex decimator that needs to interpolate vertex colors on a mesh. I'm reading [Level of Detail for 3D Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123991811) for domain material. In the color interpolation secion, the book goes on to suggest using the [CIE-L*u*v*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV) color space to perform perceptual linear interpolation of colors.

The translation equations to and from the [CIE XYZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space) color space are provided. I am able to implement the equations it provides, but Wikipedia leaves out numeric values of the following variables: u'<sub>n</sub>, v'<sub>n</sub>, and Y<sub>n</sub>.

The article say these values depend on a "specified white point" and its "luminance". It suggests u'<sub>n</sub> = 0.2009 and v'<sub>n</sub> = 0.4610 when using 2° observer and standard illuminant C. If I am using these, what would Y<sub>n</sub> be? I do not know enough physics to figure this out, and I have been unable to search for an answer on Google.

In the end, my question boils down to: What are satisfactory/appropriate values I can use for u'<sub>n</sub>, v'<sub>n</sub>, and Y<sub>n</sub>?

Also, I'm assuming I simply linearly interpolate piecewise each component of CIE-L*u*v* (L*, u*, and v*) when interpolating values in this color space. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

These three values are left out its because they depend on the colorspace of the specific device (e.g. display, printer or camera). Since computer screens use an RGB colorspace where perceived grey are R=B=G, you can assume that the values are not device dependant. *I can't remember the values of by heart, so I'll edit them in later*.

The human eye perceives luminance/intensity logarithmically, however, a linear interpolation is close enough, especially since you don't know what the actual min and max screen levels are.

The human eye perceives the color angle linearly, however, you need to take into account that the angle id's cyclic, therefore, the interpolation of the min and max angles should equal min (or max) and not the half way point. E.g. average of purple and red should be purple.

I think that the perception of saturation is also logarithmic, however, can be approximated by a linear interpolation.

**Edit:**

It seems like most sites use the sRGB to XYZ formulas.

http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html
http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=02#text2
http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-xyz